# Confidence intervals on predictions for a Bayesian linear regression model

Tags: r

I was looking at [an excellent post on Bayesian Linear Regression (MHadaptive)](http://www.r-bloggers.com/general-bayesian-estimation-using-mhadaptive/)

giving an output for 
 posterior Credible Intervals

```
BCI(mcmc_r)
#              0.025       0.975
# slope       -5.3345970   6.841016
# intercept    0.4216079   1.690075
# epsilon      3.8863393   6.660037
```

What function do I now use to  construct a model with confidence intervals from these parameters?

Comment: I don't understand- posterior credible intervals *are* the Bayesian equivalent of confidence intervals. Why isn't that what you want?

Comment: Are you seeking point estimates of the intercept and slope, a and b?  If so, without running the code myself, I suspect you just use mean(a) and mean(b).

Comment: Did you download and look at the files posted at the bottom of this page?  I suspect the R code provided there will return the point estimates and credible intervals.  https://sites.google.com/site/mcgillbgsa/workshops/bayesian

Comment: How do I calculate the probability distribution of y
at any point x from these parameters?
I apologise if this is obvious.

Comment: What I did was to take all the different combinations of the upper and lower limits of the slope, intercept and error and then find the mean and standard deviation for each point in y, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to proceed.

Comment: That's indeed not right, the procedure below is good (it takes into account the correlations among the estimated parameters).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use the distributions you obtained from the MCMC to predict a distribution of `y` from any point `x`? In the example you're using, here are the relevant sections, where eggmass = y and length = x

```
##@  3.1  @##

## Function to compute predictions from the posterior
## distribution of the salmon regression model
predict_eggmass<-function(pars,length)
{
    a <- pars[, 1]      #intercept
    b <- pars[, 2]      #slope
    sigma <- pars[, 3]  #error    
    pred_mass <- a + b * length 
    pred_mass <- rnorm(length(a), pred_mass, sigma)
    return(pred_mass)
}

###  --  ###
##@  3.2  @##

## generate prediction
pred_length <- 80     # predict for an 80cm individual
pred <- predict_eggmass(mcmc_salmon$trace, length=pred_length)
## Plot prediction distribution
hist(pred, breaks=30, main='', probability=TRUE)

## What is the 95% BCI of the prediction?
pred_BCI <- quantile(pred, p=c(0.025, 0.975))
    2.5%    97.5% 
33.61029 43.16795
```

I think the distribution you refer to in your comment is available here as `pred` and the  confidence interval is `pred_BCI`.

Comment: I think the OP may want the confidence intervals (i.e. skipping the `rnorm` step in your `predict_eggmass` function) rather than the prediction intervals (which is what you have here).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a look in the posterior marginal density for each parameter, you can use `density()` with the samples that are stored in the `trace` component of the `mcmc_r` object.

```
library(MHadaptive)
data(mcmc_r)

BCI(mcmc_r)
#              0.025    0.975   post_mean
# a       -6.6113522 7.038858 0.001852978
# b        0.2217377 1.543519 0.902057671
# epsilon  3.8094802 6.550360 4.957292114

head(mcmc_r$trace)
#           [,1]      [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 3.1448136 0.7211228 5.449728
# [2,] 2.2287645 0.7155189 4.602004
# [3,] 2.0812509 0.8035820 4.224071
# [4,] 1.2444855 0.8448825 4.737466
# [5,] 3.2765630 0.5947548 4.740052
# [6,] 0.4271876 0.9014841 5.333821

plot(density(mcmc_r$trace[,3]), main=mcmc_r$par_names[3])
```

[image]